# Geometric data structure for storing points from [0, 1)^d with toroidal topology

Tags: c++, c++20, computational-geometry, boost-geometry, r-tree

I need to store points from [0, 1)^d and query the data structure for either the k-nearest points or all points with difference less than a given epsilon; both relative to some reference point y.

Now the crucial thing is that I do not want to use Euclidean distance, but a toroidal distance (i.e. with a wrap arround occurring at the borders of [0, 1)^d.

I‘ve previously used boost::geometry::index::rtree for that, but I need to query this with boost::geometry::index::satisfies and that is really slow. The only thing which is fast is boost::geometry::index::nearest, but this is relative to Euclidean distance.

I guess I really need a data structure which is designed to store points with the toroidal topology. Is there already somethinh out there or do I need to implement this on my own?

Comment: Do you need to take into account the curvature of the torus, or does a flat torus suffice? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Flat_torus *(disclaimer: I don't know the answer in either case, but I think the second might be easier)*

Comment: @joergbrech I don't think we need to make things that complicated. We simply replace the Euclidean norm by $\|x\| = \sqrt{\sum_i |x_i|^2}$, where $|x| := \min(|x|, 1 - |x|)$.